# PHP Conditionally Combining Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looping through an array of days in the current month to generate another array of days that are on or after the current day. I'm also doing the same for the next month (which will always include all days as they are after the current date).

The complexity is when the next month is in a different year to the current month. The format of the final array is like this:

```
array("year" => array("month" => array(days)));
```

When both months are in the same year it might look like this:

```
$allDays = array("2013" => array( "11" => array(28,29,30), "12" => array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31)));
```

When the 2 months are in different years (i.e. Dec and Jan) it might look like this:

```
$allDays = array("2013" => array("12" => array(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31)), "2014" => array("1" => array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31) )) ;
```

Here's my code that generates the list of dates for the current month and the next month:

```
// Set the default timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');

    // Get days for current month
    $day = date("Y-m-d");
    $i = strtotime($day);

    array("year" => array("month" => array(days)));
    $linked_days = array(
        date('Y', $i) => array(
            date('m') => range(date('d', $i), intval(date('t'))),
        ),
    );

    // Get days for next month

    $day2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('first day of next month')) ;
    $i2 = strtotime($day2);

    array("year" => array("month" => array(days)));
    $linked_days2 = array(
        date('Y', $i2) => array(
            date('m') => range(date('d', $i2), intval(date('t'))),
        ),
    );
```

I'm not sure how to go about combining them into the 1 array with a different sytanx if they are in the same year or not?

Comment: What is days in e.g. `array("year" => array("month" => array(days)))` ? You're not even using that line, also.

Comment: This seems like it would be easier using non-string representations for the dates. Something sequential like `timestamps`, then it's just a matter of formatting back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there is already an entry for the year in your array with `isset` function :

Change this

```
$day2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('first day of next month')) ;
$i2 = strtotime($day2);

array("year" => array("month" => array(days)));
$linked_days2 = array(
    date('Y', $i2) => array(
        date('m') => range(date('d', $i2), intval(date('t'))),
    ),
);
```

To

```
$day2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('first day of next month')) ;
$i2 = strtotime($day2);

array("year" => array("month" => array(days))); //useless line ??
if(!isset($linked_days[date('Y', $i2)])){
    //if no entry for this year in array, create new entry
    $linked_days[date('Y', $i2)] = array(date('m') => range(date('d', $i), intval(date('t'))));
}
else{
    //else, just add the month entry
    $linked_days[date('Y', $i2)][date('m')] = range(date('d', $i2), intval(date('t'))) ;
}
```